# Parallel.ForEach stops being parallel for the last few items

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I have an external singlethreaded program that needs to be run multiple hundred times with different parameters. To make it faster I want to run it once for each core at the same time. To do that I used Parallel.ForEach running on a list with the different parameters to pass to the external program:

```
var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions {
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount // 8 for me
};

Parallel.ForEach(ListWithAllTheParams, parallelOptions, DoTheStuff);

...

private void DoTheStuff(ParamType parameter, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState, long index)
{
    // prepare process parameters etc.
    theProcess.Start();
    theProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Pretty straightforward and works nicely... until the last ~10 items - they don't get parallelized for some reason and just run one after another. I've confirmed this by looking at the cpu usage and the running programs in the Task Manager.

This does not happen when I populate the parameter list with only a few (say, 10) items.

Can somebody explain this behavior to me? Any hints or tips appreciated!

Comment: In a library that I built some time ago to use multi threading, the process was dividing the items list in blocks whose dimension depends on the total item count. When a core (thread) completes a block, he gets the next block to process from blocks list. If the .NET native parrallel implementation uses the same principle, you will have at end of execution only one thread running (all others terminated) and completing the process for the last items of the block.

Comment: are you sure? checking multitasking with task manager is not so accurate. try `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads`. this will give you the current number of threads.

Comment: @Graffito that sounds pretty logical, yeah.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I can see that only one instance of the external program is running in the end, even though it's not the last remaining run of it.

Comment: Run it without the MaxDegreeOfParallelism. You asked for a ceiling, you're getting it.

Comment: @Graffito Sure? Since `Parallel.ForEach` is available for `IEnumerable<T>`, the total number of items isn't available on invocation.
I think the `Parallel.ForEach` simply does not guarantee that the action will be executed in another thread (just like with Task).

Comment: take a look at this [topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/26/9641563.aspx) and try writing custom Parallel.Foreach see what happens...

Comment: @nikee: Your remark is really relevant. I don't know how the Parralel.Foreach is implemented. Perhaps, a first foreach is done to get all IEnumerable Items, or not ... _Or process differs if the IEnumerable is a ICollection_

Comment: @nikeee & Graffito: Looking into the Reference Source it seems the Framework can take shortcuts when the IEnumerable is actually an Array or an IList: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs#L2258

Comment: Further down I found out about [partitioners.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner(v=vs.110).aspx) These seem to control exactly what @Graffito mentioned in the first post. Over [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411(v=vs.110).aspx) different kinds of partitioners are discussed, and a dynamic/chunk partitoner with just one item per chunk seems to be the solution. It is even implemented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997416(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm going to test it tomorrow and hope that's the solution!

Comment: Sidenote: The increased overhead of using such small chunks is negligible for me since the external processes take multiple seconds to minutes to complete.

Comment: @SeriTools If you are using .NET 4.5 it now includes a one item per chunk partitioner. [`Partitioner.Create(yourSource, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136328(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Wow, that's exactly what I neeeded! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

With Scott's tip in the comments above changing it to the following code made it behave as I wanted:

```
OrderablePartitioner<ParamType> partitioner =
    Partitioner.Create(ListWithAllTheParams, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);

var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions {
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount // 8 for me
};

Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, parallelOptions, DoTheStuff);
```

Thanks a lot!